# Issue with pip installing Tensorflow in Windows? no matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the following error message. Have tried to upgrade pip, and checked the common problems on the tensorflow website as well as some threads here on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work? any ideas? I am trying to install it in an anaconda environment with python 2.7
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow. No matching distribution found for tensorflow.

Comment: have you tried with `conda` anaconda package manager ?

Comment: You need to use Python 3.5, 64-bit.  No other version currently works -- even 3.6 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using Python 3.5 (64 bit) or greater. See the installation instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows).

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip. As of writting TensorFlow requires Python 3.4–3.7 (64bit)